# Toolbar for kitkat

Tags: toolbar, android-4.4-kitkat, android-toolbar, android-cardview

I have a problem with my toolbar when using my KitKat device. On my lollipop device everything works fine.
The problem is that my toolbar doesnt notice my touch in my action button in the toolbar.
I've already tried using a cardview but that didnt helped me.
Also with the cardview my toolbar doesnt fill the hole space in my KitKat device

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#0610DB"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0610DB"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```